# Java equals plus operator

Tags: java, operators, equals-operator

I need to explain this strange operator **=+** (equal plus)

Example #1:

```
Double a = new Double(5);
Double b = new Double(10);
a += b
```

result:

```
a=15.0
b=10.0
```

Example #2:

```
Double a = new Double(5);
Double b = new Double(10);
a =+ b
```

result:

```
a=10.0
b=10.0
```

I understand the first example, but please explain me what this **=+** operator did in example no.2.

And another interesting fact is, that these operators are valid and compilable:
+=, -=, *=, /=
but any of these two won't compile:
=*, =/

Comment: `a = +b` is equivalent to `a = b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=+` is the assignment operation and the unary `+` afterwards. It's perfectly valid and what happens is:

```
a = (+b);
```

It's pretty much the same when you want to assign the negative value of a variable to another variable:

```
a = (-b); //a will be assigned with -10
```

Also, `=*` doesn't compile, because there's no `*` unary operator.